# AngularJS information window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, popup

I would like to popup a little label or something like that which diffuse a result from my JS code.

for now, I got a table :

```
        <table cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>bucketName</th>
                <th>creationDate</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="bucket in listBucket">
                <td>{{bucket.name}}</td>
                <td>{{bucket.creationDate}}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/ui/#/buckets" ng-click="getPolicy(bucket.name)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></a>
                    <a href="/ui/#/buckets" ng-confirm-click confirmed-click="deleteBucket(bucket.name)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And I would like to press :

`<a href="/ui/#/buckets" ng-click="getPolicy(bucket.name)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></a>`

getPolicy() only return if my bucket is READONLY, WRITEONLY, READWRITE, NONE.
That's the only informations I want to display.

Here's my function on server side :

```
    getPolicy(request, response, args) {

    minioClient.getBucketPolicy(args.bucketName, '', function (err, policy) {
        if (policy) {
            if (err) {
                if (err.code !== "NoSuchBucketPolicy") {
                    throw err
                }
                console.log(err);
            }
            return response.setData(policy).apply();
        }
        else
            return response.setData("none").apply();
    })
}
```

And I got the response there on my client side :

```
        $scope.getPolicy = function (bucketName) {
        $scope.bucketRequest = new $vRequest()
            .list('buckets', encodeURIComponent(bucketName))
            .el("policy")
            .get(function (err, res, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                }
                else {
                    console.log(data);
                    $scope.listPolicy = data;
                }
            })
    }
```

Probably with a onclick() function on my control but I don't know how I can manage to do that.

Any idea please? :)

Comment: Have you written the getPolicy() function in controller? What is the error, if any? Please elaborate with the JS code .

Comment: Yup, this function already worked, I wrote it on my server side and it return the response on my client side with .apply()

Comment: Have you tried removing the href tag from the anchor ? (href="/ui/#/buckets" )

Comment: The problem is that I would like to get the result of my function in a kind of little window or label which will appear by a click on my `<a href="/ui/#/buckets" ng-click="getPolicy(bucket.name)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></a>`

Comment: @AvinashTiwari, this will not resolve my problem. I mean I probably will remove the href tag but It will not show a window like I want. I just don't know which control I should use to do that.

Comment: @Cupkek05, since you get your response in  $scope.listPolicy = data;  On your ng-click function, write the logic to display listPolicy in the html in an alert/modal, anything you want.